# DataTables.net : Change theme of grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables, themes

I am new to [DataTables.net](https://datatables.net/)
Found the feature of these JS datatables amazing. However, to use this in our application we have to change the UI (color). Currently is grey based. Have to change it to blue based. Kindly let know if there is any config / setting to change the theme.

Comment: https://datatables.net/manual/styling/theme-creator

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of ways to alter the UI of datatables. You can find more information here https://www.datatables.net/examples/styling/

My favorite way of styling datatables and is what I recommend is using [jQueryUI Theme Roller](https://www.datatables.net/examples/styling/jqueryUI.html)
To implement this you have to load also the following files:

- dataTables.jqueryui.min.js
- dataTables.jqueryui.min.css

Both of these files can be downloaded from [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) website, in the zip file after selecting to download the library (self made UI or ready made)

Here is also a [live example](http://live.datatables.net/xeqihoju/1/edit) for your reference

Hope that helps